# Android call intent multi numbers selection

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I have an ImageButton that trigger the Call Intent. I want to know if it is possible to pass 2 numbers as data, so that when you tap the button, it opens automatically a popup which let you choose the number to call. This should be the default Android behavior for your contacts, if you have more than one number associated with the contact you're trying to call, it gives you the options.

my code is something like this:

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("1234567890"));
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

I tried to put multiple number separeted by semi colon, but is not working:

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("1234567890;0987654321"));
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks
Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there exits any such thing programmatically.

But you can try something like this,On click of image button :

1) If only 1 number, use the code you have written.

2) If multiple numbers, open a dialog box(You need to create that all by yourself) and let user choose the number, and then redirect the number to your code

Comment: Note that in android there is different dialog box' AlertDialog is probably the one you'd want to make.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it was possible, but I guess you're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.text.Html;
    import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView tv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            attachUi();
            //getPattern();
        }

        private void attachUi() {
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
            tv.setOnClickListener(clk);
        }

        private View.OnClickListener clk = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gotoCall();
            }
        };

        private void gotoCall() {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("08698511503");
            list.add("07666175151");
            list.add("0548554552");



            TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            TelephonyMgr.listen(new PhoneCallListener(this, list), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            //startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    }



    // create new class

    class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        int count = 0;
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> list;

        public PhoneCallListener(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> list) {
            this.context = mainActivity;
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "List Size ::" + list);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside Ringing State::");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    String phone_number = null;
                    Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside Idle State::");
                    if (list.size() > count) {
                        phone_number = list.get(count);
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (phone_number != null) {
                        nextCalling(phone_number);
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside OFFHOOK State::");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void nextCalling(String phone_number) {
            Intent callIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent1.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            context.startActivity(callIntent1);
        }
    }

// in manifest add permission..

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```